# How to create template tags in django and use Form?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

I create custom django template and used Form:

This is file ratings.py use tags:

```
from django import template
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
from Ratings.forms import RatingsForm

register = template.Library()

class RatingFormNode(template.Node):
    def __init__(self, content, id, varname):
        self.content = content.split('.')
        self.varname = varname
        self.id = template.Variable(id)

    def render(self, context):
        id = self.id.resolve(context)
        content = ContentType.objects.get(app_label=self.content[0], model=str(self.content[1]).lower())
        context[self.varname] = RatingsForm(initial={'content_type': content, 'object_id': id})
        return ''

@register.tag(name='rating')
def rating(parser, token):
    """
    {% rating appname.Modelname 1 as Newsletter_Form %}
    """
    bits = token.split_contents()

    if bits[3] != 'as':
        raise template.TemplateSyntaxError, "third argument to the get_latest tag must be 'as'"

    return RatingFormNode(bits[1], bits[2], bits[4])
```

and I use this tag in tempalte file:

```
{% rating appname.Modelname id as rating_form %}
<form action="{% url 'ratings_add' %}" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ rating_form }}
    <input type="hidden" name="url" value="{{ post.slug }}" />
    <input type="submit" value="Wyślij" />
</form>
```

this is urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url

urlpatterns = patterns('Ratings.views',
    url(r'^add/$', 'ratings_add', name='ratings_add'),
)
```

and create views to get the url:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.http.response import Http404
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from Ratings.forms import RatingsForm


def ratings_add(request):
    if not request.method == 'POST':
        return Http404
    form = RatingsForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('post', args=[request.POST.get('url')]))
    else:
        request.session['form_data'] = request.POST
        return redirect(reverse('post', args=[request.POST.get('url')]), form=form)
```

I use this tag in the template with the url: "/post/name-this-post/".
Tag creates a form of "RatingForm" of the model "Rating". When the person viewing your page and use the form and form is valid this is work (save form and redirect to page "/post/name-this-post/"), but when an error occurs, you are redirected but does not display an error. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, will try include block to your template file:

> ```
> {% for field in form %}
>     <div class="fieldWrapper">
>         {{ field.errors }}
>         {{ field.label_tag }} {{ field }}
>     </div>
> {% endfor %}
> ```

Secondly, Is exist view `post` at the `views.py` for `redirect(reverse('post', args=[request.POST.get('url')]), form=form)`? Besides exist entry `url(...)` of the `urlpatterns` at the `urls.py` for `post` view? If both exists add it it to question's code

Comment: 1. when i use standard form tags all method is included (errors, label etc.) 
2. Yes, def post exist, but this definition respons only post name, content etc. I want to build a form tag. Ratings Form is very common on the site and I do not want to initiate a view.